# Closing Popup after clicking child button using no code-behind

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a wpf application with a toggle window which opens a popup control. I want to be able to close it after the user clicks it's child button.

My preference would be to do it in the xaml via style triggers. But for some reason I can't set my popup **IsOpen** property inside of the event trigger. I receive an error saying

```
A value of type setter cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type TriggerActionCollection
```

here's how I have the xaml set up

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="ShowAvailableOptionsToggleButton"
                                              Content="Add Options" />

<Popup IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=ShowAvailableOptionsToggleButton}">
                <StackPanel>
                    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableOptions}"
                              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                              DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
                    <Button Content="Add"
                            Name="AddOptionBtn"
                            Command="{Binding AddOptionCommand}"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <Popup.Style>
                   <Style>
                       <Style.Triggers>
                          <EventTrigger SourceName="AddOptionBtn" RoutedEvent="Button.Click"> 
                             //ERROR HAPPENS HERE
                             <Setter Property="IsOpen" Value="False"/>
                          </EventTrigger>
                       </Style.Triggers>
                   </Style>
                </Popup.Style>
            </Popup>
```

Can someone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EventTrigger` has to be used with animations:

```
<Popup IsOpen="True">
  <Button x:Name="AddOptionBtn"
          Content="Add" />
  <Popup.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger SourceName="AddOptionBtn" 
                  RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
      <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
          <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.Target="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Popup}}"
                                          Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen">
            <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                     Value="False" />
          </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
  </Popup.Triggers>
</Popup>
```

Comment: oh I see. I didn't realize that I had to use animation to set the popup properties. Thank you for the assist.

Comment: You don't need animations to set the properties of a `Popup`. If you use `EventTrigger`, _then_ you have to animate the properties.